# java xmlpull parse random string from XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm very new to Android programming and I'm trying to figure out how to get strings from a file and display those strings on buttons randomly.

The goal is to make a multiple choice test with randomly generated questions (based on a database) and keep track of the user's correct and incorrect answers (but I'm far from that part).

I watched an xmlpull tutorial which showed me how to pull a section of every line in the document and I tried to adapt it to pull a section of one line.  Here's what I have:

```java
String item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    try {
        item = getItemFromXML(this);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    String[] items = item.split("\n");
    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

}

public String getItemFromXML(Test test) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Resources res = test.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.database);
    xpp.next();
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    for (int sCount = 0; sCount<1; sCount++) {
        if (eventType ==XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (xpp.getName().equals("character")) {
                stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "english")  + "\n");
            }
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

The XML file looks kind of like this:

```xml
<root id="kanji">
  <characters>
    <character english="one" grade="1"/>
```

How can I make this work to pull a value from a random line?

Comment: Unless you know exactly how many "lines" *(you mean <character> elements)* you have, you can't generate an appropriate random number.

Comment: You should probably parse the file as a whole and store its data into a collection. Choose a random element from that collection to display. That's way more efficient.

Comment: @jangroth I will try to figure out how to do that.  It does make sense.  Thank you.